# Check if column data exists in column and return value of the another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to check if values from column B exist in column A, and if yes and equal with the value in that row, create another column D, getting the value from column C (for the A on that row).

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | f | 12 | 55 |
| b | a | 23 | 12 |
| c | b | 33 | 23 |
| d | c | 1 | 33 |
| e | e | 11 | 11 |
| f | d | 55 | 1 |

This is what I have, but it's not working as it should as it is setting the value of D by just checking if the value exists in column A and not comparing them.

```
  ifelse(df$B %in% df$A, df$C , NA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do:

```
transform(df1, D = setNames(C,A)[B])

  A B  C  D
1 a f 12 55
2 b a 23 12
3 c b 33 23
4 d c  1 33
5 e e 11 11
6 f d 55  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `match`.  By default, if there is no match, it returns `NA`, indexing on `NA` returns NA for 'C' as well

```
df1$D <-  with(df1, C[match(B, A)])
```

-output

```
> df1
  A B  C  D
1 a f 12 55
2 b a 23 12
3 c b 33 23
4 d c  1 33
5 e e 11 11
6 f d 55  1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), B = c("f", 
"a", "b", "c", "e", "d"), C = c(12L, 23L, 33L, 1L, 11L, 55L), 
    D = c(55L, 12L, 23L, 33L, 11L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```